# Initialise all classes inside a package as Beans without declaring them with @Component annotation

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a package `com.org.pages` inside which there are more than 40 classes.

I want to get all these classes initialised via Spring as Beans. Now I don't want to go and add `@Component` for each class in that package.

**Question 1:** Is there any other way around to achieve this without annotating all these classes with `@Component` to treat them as beans?

**Question 2:** Once I annotate these classes with @Component annotation, do I need to `@Autowire` references of these classes somewhere to **actually** create instances of them?

Comment: You are complicating yourself if you don't want to add the `@Component`. Simple is always safer than inventing some sort of complicated solution. Spring does not have a way to guess what java beans to instantiate without telling it what needs to instantiate. So either `@Component` or you instantiate it with `@Bean`

Comment: But I do want to go ahead and tell that "consider all classes inside this package as beans and initialize them". Isn't that enough?

Comment: Man It seems that you want an easy way, but as @sfat said the Simple is always safer than inventing some sort of complicated solution
however if you do need a solution regardless of how hard is it please take a look at my answer

Comment: Add an include filter to an `@ComponentScan`. the default is to detect all `@Compont` annotated classes but you can write your own filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own bean definition,

do something like that

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package.prefix", new SubTypesScanner(false));
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for (Class clazz : allClasses) {
      GenericBeanDefinition gbd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
      gbd.setBeanClass(clazz);
      gbd.setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
      registry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getSimpleName() + "RegisteredBean", gbd);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    // Custom post process the existing bean definitions
  }
}
```

by this way you will register all classes as beans in the provided package

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Basil.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) of the `@ComponentScan` annotation should give you some insight. One thing you will notice is the [`includeFilters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#includeFilters--) argument. You can specify with this what to include. The default filters include classes that have the `@Component` annotation.

If you look at the [`@Filter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.Filter.html) annotation you can see that there are several [types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FilterType.html). The type you want here is the REGEX filter type. You define an expression and if the expression matches the class will become a component.

```
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = 
    @Filter(type=FilterType.REGEXP, 
            pattern= {"com.org.pages..*.*" )
```

Something like the above should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own configuration class. In your configuration class you can define all the beans with @Bean annotation. Also you can do your DI there. 
Imagine you have a UserDao class and a UserServcie class. And UserService has a userDao. Then the configuration file will be like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public UserDao userDao(){
    return new UserDao();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserService userService(){
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    userService.setUserDao(userDao());
    return userService;
    }

}
```